# Toolbar does not display the overflow icon

Tags: android, android-toolbar

My app has `minSDKVersio=11` and a `targetSDKVersion=22`. I am running the app on a GalaxyNexus emulator running on API14.

My activity has a Toolbar in the layout. The Toolbar is imported from the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` library.

Here is the content of the menu resource for populating the Toolbar. The filename is homeview_menu_common.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
    android:title="XXX"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

<item 
    android:id="@+id/homeview_toolbar_overflow_logout"
    android:title="@string/homeview_toolbar_overflow_logout"
    app:showAsAction="always">
</item>
</menu>
```

My problem is: The overflow menu is not displayed at all. Since GalaxyNexus does not have a hardware options button, the overflow menu should be visible in the Toolber. I also find that the `onCreatOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` is never called.

Update: Posting the activity code

```
public class HomeView extends GenericActivity<HomeOps.View, HomeOps> implements HomeOps.View {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homeview_layout);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, HomeOps.class, this);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.homeview_toolbar);
    Boolean show = toolbar.showOverflowMenu();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.homeview_menu_common, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


}
```

Comment: Change app:showAsAction="always" to app:showAsAction="ifRoom".

Comment: can you confirm if your are trying all this inside fragment or inside activity ?

Comment: @dex I am trying this inside an activity

Comment: @DhavalPatel `ifRoom` did not make any difference. `never` also did not make any difference. As I understand, `never` would force the menu item to go into the overflow menu

Comment: @Amit please post your activity code?

Comment: @DhavalPatel I updated the main description with the activity code

Answer (score 1):

1) Replace `app:showAsAction="always"` by `app:showAsAction="never"`

2) Your basic activity implementation should look like like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.homeview_menu_common, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_favorite:
            // Do your stuff for favorite menu item
            break;

        case R.id.homeview_toolbar_overflow_logout:
            // Do your stuff for homeview_toolbar_overflow_logout menu item
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

3) Use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` as your Activity theme. If you don'
t want to add the `ActionBar` from your theme, be sure to call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` in the `onCreate()` :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.homeview_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Comment: My activity cannot extend AppCompatActivity because it is already extending another activity as part of the Model-View_Presenter design pattern

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem as follows:

Use `Toolbar.inflateMenu()` to inflate the menu items in the Toolbar.
Use `Toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener()` to set a click listener.